# Azure B2B Integration Fails with Office 365 APIs

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365-apps, office365api

In doing some more testing today, I am finding that when I get an access token for a user that has been added to a tenant via the Azure B2B feature, I cannot access the site content using the Office 365 APIs.

Is there any plan to enable this scenario by RTM for Azure B2B?  I'm finding more and more blocking scenarios like this where a user has been granted access to a resource, but access through the Office 365 APIs is not working.